# How can I create a delegate to read a property of an anonymous type?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a method that is called with an instance of an anonymous type. The type is always the same, but the instance is different.

*NOTE*: I am passed the anonymous object simply as a type `object`.

I know the anonymous type has a property named `Request` of type `HttpRequestMessage`. Here is my method that is executed with the anonymous type in `info.Value`.

```cs
void IObserver<KeyValuePair<string, object> event> OnNext(KeyValuePair<string, object> info)
{
  HttpRequestMessage request = ?????
}
```

I can get the property getter like so:

```cs
MethodInfo propertyGetter = type.GetProperty("Request").GetGetMethod();
```

But I can't afford the cost of reflection when reading the property of the instance passed to me.

How can I create a delegate that I pass the instance to and get the property value?

I tried this

```cs
private delegate HttpRequestMessage RequestPropertyGetterDelegate(object instance);
private static RequestPropertyGetterDelegate RequestPropertyGetter;

private static RequestPropertyGetterDelegate CreateRequestFromPropertyDelegate(Type type)
{
    MethodInfo propertyGetter = type.GetProperty("Request").GetGetMethod();
    return (RequestPropertyGetterDelegate)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(RequestPropertyGetterDelegate), propertyGetter);
}
```

But I am experiencing a binding error

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the target method because its signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type.'

Comment: You "can't afford the cost of reflection" but you go on to create a piece of code that uses *both* Reflection and delegates? If the type is the same, why aren't you just caching the MethodInfo? https://dotnetfiddle.net/GecXYf

Comment: The `params` doesn't make sense in this instance, and the `object instance` parameter will fail it anyway.

Comment: If you create a delegate from a MethodInfo then it doesn't use reflection. So you can reflect once to find the MethodInfo, and then avoid reflection from there onwards.

Comment: You can't because the type is unknown. There is a workaround, will post

Comment: @PeterMorris That doesn't answer the second part of my comment

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Because I don't want the MethodInfo (which uses reflection to invoke), I want to cache a delegate

Comment: Expression trees would do the job here, and would be much performant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is, using expression trees.
All you have to do is cache the `getter`, the performance should be the same as direct access.

```
void Main()
{
    var instance = new TestClass { Request = "Something 2" };
    var getter = CreateRequestFromPropertyDelegate(typeof(TestClass));
    // Cache getter per type
    var value = getter(instance);
    Console.WriteLine(value); // Prints "Something 2"
}

private delegate string RequestPropertyGetterDelegate(object instance);

static RequestPropertyGetterDelegate CreateRequestFromPropertyDelegate(Type type)
{
    // Entry of the delegate
    var instanceParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "instance");
    
    // Cast the instance from "object" to the correct type
    var instanceExpr = Expression.TypeAs(instanceParam, type);
    
    // Get the property's value
    var property = type.GetProperty("Request");
    var propertyExpr = Expression.Property(instanceExpr, property);
    
    // Create delegate
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<RequestPropertyGetterDelegate>(propertyExpr, instanceParam);
    return lambda.Compile();
}

class TestClass
{
    // Using string here because I'm on LINQPad
    public string Request { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using some expression trees it should be:

```
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<object, string>> extractorsCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<object, string>>();

public static string GetRequest(object obj)
{
    Type type = obj.GetType();

    Func<object, string> extractor = extractorsCache.GetOrAdd(type, BuildExtractor);

    string res = extractor(obj);

    return res;
}

public static Func<object, string> BuildExtractor(Type type)
{
    var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
    var prop = Expression.Property(Expression.TypeAs(par, type), "Request");
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, string>>(prop, par).Compile();
}
```

and then:

```
string r1 = GetRequest(new { Request = "Foo" });
string r2 = GetRequest(new { Request = "Bar" });
string r3 = GetRequest(new { Request = "Baz" });
string r4 = GetRequest(new { Request = "Zoo", Ix = 1 });
```

Note that the compiled expression trees are cached in a `ConcurrentDictionary<,>`, so these four `GetRequest` will generate two compiled expressions (because in the end there are two anonymous types here).

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to do this without Genric-ising the function you are writing it in. Because the anonymous type is more specific than `object`, an `object` parameter will never bind.

You can work around this by putting the whole thing in a static generic class:

```cs
static class AnonHelper<T>
{
    public readonly Func<T, HttpRequestMessage> Getter = (Func<T, HttpRequestMessage>)
        Delegate.CreateDelegate(
        typeof(Func<T, HttpRequestMessage>, propertyGetter)),
        typeof(T)
        .GetProperty("Request")
        .GetGetMethod()
        );
        
}
```

You still cannot access it as you cannot declare the generic parameter.

So wrap it in a function on the outside (you could even make it an extension):

```cs
HttpRequestMessage GetProp<T>(T obj)
{
    return AnonHelper<T>.Getter(obj);
}
```

You can then call it like so:

`GetProp(anonObj)`

This only works if you can call `GetProp` at the point where the type of the anonymous object is statically known, usually the same method it is declared in.

Comment: anonObj will always be of type `object` - so this won't help me will it?

Comment: Depends if you are still at the point where it is declared with `var`, there you still have access to the type

Comment: No, the object is passed to be (updated the question).

Comment: Then it is obviously impossible. You can't access your cache without reflection